# 404 when a JS file requires another JS file without .js extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, http-status-code-404

I am getting 404 Not Found when a JS file requires another JS file and in the require statement it does not specify .js extension.

I have a file called CalendarUtils.js, which requires some modules from date-fns:

`module.exports = factory(require("date-fns/add_days/index"));`

I am getting 404:

`[1] 16.11.14 10:45:55 404 GET /lib/date-fns/add_days/index`

If I change CalendarUtils.js as:

`module.exports = factory(require("date-fns/add_days/index.js"));`

Then it works.

I am wondering why this is happening. This is happening at several places and I 
would prefer not to make changes everywhere. I am using Angular2.

My date-fns index file:

```
gaurav:application gaurav$ tree build/lib/date-fns/add_days/
build/lib/date-fns/add_days/
└── index.js
```

Please ask me any question if needed. Thanks a lot.

System config file for angular2 to know the file locations:

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'lib/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'date-fns': 'npm:date-fns',
            'angular-calendar': 'npm:angular-calendar/dist/umd/angular-calendar.js',
            'angular-resizable-element': 'npm:angular-resizable-element/dist/umd/angular-resizable-element.js',
            'calendar-utils': 'npm:calendar-utils/dist/umd/calendarUtils.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

I needed to specify defaultExtension in systemjs config file:

```
packages: {
        app: {
            main: './main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'date-fns': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use relative paths (or absolute paths) when requiring local project files:

`module.exports = factory(require("./date-fns/add_days/index"));`

Otherwise, `require()` will treat it like it's a module name, and look for an installed module named `date-fns/add_days/index`, and will obviously fail.

Also, in this case you could ommit the `index.js` file name, because `require()` already looks for `index.js` when you require a directory:

`module.exports = factory(require("./date-fns/add_days"));`

Hope it helps.

Comment: date-fns folder is under node_modules while development.. and it is under lib folder while serving. So, I can't use relative path. I have system configuration for angular2 to find the location of file in updated question. Config file works for all modules except date-fns. I am putting the config file in the updated original question.

Comment: Angular2 is finding the location of index.js file without the relative path because of angular2 configuration.. I just don't understand why it is not finding it without '.js' extension.